# minimizing parse requests while looping through array

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform, cloud

I'm working on a pet project using parse as a back end. I'm setting up a viewcontroller that contains a list of people you can possibly add as "friends"; these are people that 
a) exist in your contacts list and 
b) have already downloaded the app and signed up.

Different buttons will be displayed depending on their status as a user (invite button if they only exist in your contacts list, add to friends button if they're also using the app already).

I'm trying to keep my Parse account to 30 requests/second so that I'm not out of pocket for a pet app.

One way I've thought to figure out who is registered as a user AND who exists in my contacts list is to loop through the contacts list on my phone and query that phone number on parse. However, this would obviously go over my limit on requests/second.

Is there a way (I've looked through Parse documentation and googled it) to take an array (list of contacts on my phone) and run a PFQuery ON THAT ARRAY, checking each object and returning matches?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a quarter million users in your app you shouldn't be much concerned, it **doesn't** work like: 1 user goes through 30 count for loop with one query each and you get 30 req/s:

**How does the requests/second limit translate to concurrent users?**

Generally when your user count doubles, your requests per second also double. However, different apps send different numbers of requests per second depending on how frequently they save objects or issue queries. We estimate that the average app's active user will issue 10 requests. Thus, if you had a million users on a particular day, and their traffic was evenly spread throughout the day, you could estimate your app would need about 10,000,000 total API requests, or about 120 requests per second. Every app is different, so we strongly encourage you to measure how many requests your users send.

I have run through loops of requests and I barely hit 1 req/s

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way (I've looked through Parse documentation and googled
>   it) to take an array (list of contacts on my phone) and run a PFQuery
>   ON THAT ARRAY, checking each object and returning matches?

Yes there is, use:

```
query?.whereKey(key: String, containedIn: [AnyObject])
```